# Ldap Basic Authentication with Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, ldap

My Ldap server, at this point, has this user:

[image]

Password of MyLdap server is admin.

My Glassfish console has this configuration:

[image]

My web.xml is this:

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>Private</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>secret</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>secure</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

My sun-web.xml has this:

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>secure</role-name>
    <group-name>users</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
```

When i want to authenticate I introduce 1 as username (uid) and catia (corresponds to userPassword) to Password.

I can´t login. What I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the glassfish LDAP configuration, but at the very minimum, your Base-DN seems to be wrong: "ou=users,ou=system" would be the correct value according to the screen-shots.

"search-bind-dn" value seems to be incorrect as well: I assume it should be the DN of your LDAP Admin user, e.g. uid=admin,ou=system.

Maybe security-role-mapping used in the sun-web.xml should have a corresponding group(s) defined in the "Assign Groups" field as well (it is empty now).